# Can you help me identify these pixel fonts?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

I'm looking for the font for "Los Koopalings Han Raptado a la Princesa... Esto es obra de Bowser."
[image]
Can you help me identify this font as well

Update I know what one of them is now the second font shown is Pixel Arial 11.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of fonts similar to the first with very minor differences (The "K", "R" and "B"). Here are a few:

[Pixelation](https://www.dafont.com/pixelation.font?text=Los%20Koopalings%20Han%20Raptado%20a%20la%20Princesa)

[04b_08](https://www.dafont.com/04b-08.font?text=Los%20Koopalings%20Han%20Raptado%20a%20la%20Princesa)

[Visitor](https://www.dafont.com/visitor.font?text=Los%20Koopalings%20Han%20Raptado%20a%20la%20Princesa)